# tomcat7 filter is using the wrong filter class path

Tags: java, servlets, intellij-idea, tomcat7

I have a class that is in a package za.co.mix.servlet.Security. it is defined in the web.xml as:

```
<filter>
  <filter-name>Security</filter-name>
  <filter-class>za.co.mix.servlet.SecurityCheck</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>Security</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/secure/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

The problem is that whenever the server starts up I get:

SEVERE: Exception starting filter Security
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: za/co/mix/servlet/Security (wrong name: za/co/admin/servlet/Security)

the wrong path that it is trying to use it the old package name.  I am using intellij and refactored the coded but somewhere and for some reason the old path is still being used. can anyone suggest what I should do. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to redeploy your deployment descriptor (web.xml).

Comment: Thank you for the speedy reply, could please clarify what you mean by redeploy the web.xml. I obviously saved the changes I made and I also tried deleting and recreating it from scratch but it did not work. So what do you mean redeploy? Thank you again

Comment: The web container probably sees the old web.xml, so by re-deploy I mean to put the new version into WEB-INF again. This can be done manually or by IDE plugin. If you are using Idea, check that you have added the web.xml in your artifact: http://wiki.jetbrains.net/intellij/Creating_a_simple_Web_application_and_deploying_it_to_Tomcat#Packing_the_Application_Data_to_Deploy